# How do I resolve the Flutterflow build error related to user records when navigating to the chat page?

Tags: flutter, reference, record, assertion, flutterflow

[The error message displays like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DvB6.png)

I m making a random chat app, and the problem happen when we're navigating to the chat page
[Parameters are send like this from the page before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKBVm.png)

I tried to regenerate all firebases datas and log on multiple users but nothing changed